# How to add multiple IPv4 Subnets to a VLAN using Allied Telesyn at9924 Switch?

Tags: networking, switch

I cannot figure out adding more than one IPv4 subnets on a VLAN using Allied Telesyn at9924 Switch

I've added the first IP using this command:

add ip int=vlan15 ip=xxx.243.117.193 mask=255.255.255.248

Now, I want to add another /29 subnets on the same VLAN (15). When I try the same command, I get this:

add ip int=vlan15 ip=xxx.79.99.17 mask=255.255.255.248

Error (3005263): Interface is already attached to IP module.

Comment: Alliedware seems to protect their core manual. What you're after is called a "secondary" ip address in Cisco terms. They might allow you to create subinterfaces ie... int vlan15.2 wish I could give you more but without documentation I can't.

Answer (score 2):

Only a single ip can be assigned per interface, but I believe you can have up to 16 logical interfaces per interface (ie. vlan1, ppp0, etc).

Just append `-#` to the interface name, like so:

```
Manager switch1> show ip int

Interface     Type     IP Address       Bc Fr PArp  Filt RIP Met.   SAMode  IPSc
Pri. Filt     Pol.Filt Network Mask     MTU   VJC   GRE  OSPF Met.  DBcast  Mul.
GArp   NotifyOSPFDown
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
LOCAL         ---      Not set          -  -  -     ---  --         Pass    --
---           ---      Not set          1500  -     ---  --         ---     ---
On
vlan1         Remote   10.1.1.113       1  n  Off   ---  01         Pass    No
---           ---      255.255.255.0    1500  -     ---  0000000001 No      Rec
On     Yes
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Manager switch1> add ip int=vlan1-1 ip=192.168.55.1 mask=255.255.255.0

Info (1005275): interface successfully added.

Manager switch1> show ip int

Interface     Type     IP Address       Bc Fr PArp  Filt RIP Met.   SAMode  IPSc
Pri. Filt     Pol.Filt Network Mask     MTU   VJC   GRE  OSPF Met.  DBcast  Mul.
GArp   NotifyOSPFDown
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
LOCAL         ---      Not set          -  -  -     ---  --         Pass    --
---           ---      Not set          1500  -     ---  --         ---     ---
On
vlan1-0       Remote   10.1.1.113       1  n  Off   ---  01         Pass    No
---           ---      255.255.255.0    1500  -     ---  0000000001 No      Rec
On     Yes
vlan1-1       Static   192.168.55.1     1  n  Off   ---  01         Pass    No
---           ---      255.255.255.0    1500  -     ---  0000000001 No      Rec
On     Yes
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The `vlan1` interface is automatically changed to `vlan1-0` to indicate there are logical interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to make a switch aware of all the subnets on the VLAN.

It will switch traffic perfectly fine without this knowledge.

Comment: Yes, but it won't route it.